# Mouse position with offset

Tags: python, pygame

I'm just getting started with Python and Pygame. I was following [this lesson (GitHub)](https://github.com/kidscancode/pygame_tutorials/tree/master/tilemap/part%2004) on how to make tile-based game. I want to implement mouse tracking, so player sprite will always look where mouse is pointed.

The game has Camera class which offsets all sprites when player moves.
I managed to do mouse tracking, but currently it shows me where it is placed on 1024 * 768 screen, while player is positioned for example on 2000 * 1000. Result: player is looking from his 2000 * 1000 position to some place 'inside' that screen.

[Lesson (GitHub)](https://github.com/kidscancode/pygame_tutorials/tree/master/tilemap/part%2004)

I want my mouse position to be shifted by the same number of pixels, so it always stays inside player camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Now you need to calculate the angle of rotation in order to rotate your player to look at the mouse position.

First, calculate a vector that it's direction points towards the mouse position.

```py
x = mousex - player.position.x
y = mousey - player.position.y
```

This results in a vector (x,y) which its direction points toward the mouse position. Why?
Because when you have two vectors, in this case, **a(mousex,mousey)** and **b(player.position.x, player.position.y)**,

the mathematics tells us that if you **subtract b from a** then you are creating *another vector quantity* that its length is the distance from **a to b** and its direction point's from **b to a**

Now calculate the angle (In radians)

```py
angle = math.atan2( x, y)
```

Now you need to convert the angle to degrees instead of radians because the next method we are going to use must use an angle in degrees.

```py
angle = (180 / math.pi) * (-angle)
```

Now rotate the image using [pygame.transform.rotate()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate)

```
rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(your_player_image, int(angle))
```

Here is important to note, that you need to use the original image which you loaded using **pygame.image.load()** and not the one you are using to blit the player.

Now apply the new image to the player:

```
player.image = rotated_image
```

Comment: Hey again! Your method is working for me, but I still have that problem with offset.
I have [screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/yyh0AS7) of what is happening to mouse when player moving further than center of 1024 * 768 screen. Also there are some parts of code.

Comment: try changing ```y = mousey - player.position.y``` with ```y = player.position.y - mousey``` and tell me if this fixes it or it reverse the behavior.

Comment: Yeah, it just reversed my sprite and it's facing opposite direction

Comment: Ok. Use again the```y = mousey - player.position.y``` but now change the code ```angle = math.atan2(x, y)``` to ```angle = math.atan2( y, x)``` and tell me the result.

Comment: I tried it and it made my sprite look in another direction plus rotation became inversed.
But that's not a problem, as I said, you first advice worked for mouse tracking itself. I'm sorry for my english, I'll try to explain differently.
Maybe I could somehow track mouse world coords, and not where it placed on the screen?

Comment: Let's say my total map size is 3000 * 2000 pixels. I have camera class that keeps player sprite centered if he moves more than half of 1024 * 768 pixels, either to the right or down. When that happens, my player world coordinates start to increase, so at some point I'm passing the limits of 1024 * 768. My coords may be x2000, y500 or x600, y1000. However, my mouse coords can't be more than screen size.
Maybe I could somehow track mouse world coords, not screen coords?

Comment: I think I didn't understand what is your issue in my previous comments. Does this problem occur when the mouse goes off the screen or when it goes under the middle of the screen?

Comment: [Look here](https://imgur.com/a/QAF1Te6)
It happens, when player moves further than 1024 * 768 (screen size). Mouse still thinks that it is placed somewhere inside that rectangle, while in fact I'm pointing it right under my player sprite at 1441x, 200y coords. As a result - player sprite is looking somewhere inside 1024 * 768 rectangle from his current position

Comment: Can I ask you something? Does the player's position changes? Or is he static? I understand that you are offseting all the other spites to make the camera effect but the player's position changes or not?

Comment: If that will help, here is my [code](https://github.com/vitalezzz98/Tile-Game)
Yeah, I believe position is changing. At least it's what my coords are showing

Comment: Hello again... I get an exception when I run your code. ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\TiledMaps\\Kenney Topdown Pack.tsx'``` Do you have a file on your computer which you didn't upload on GitHub? This error happens in the ```load_data()``` ```self.map = TiledMap(path.join(map_folder, 'tilemap.tmx'))```

Comment: Oops, my bad. I added that folder too now